# Why am I getting NaN when executing a method within my class, but not when executing in isolation?

Tags: javascript, class, math, vector, physics

I am trying to follow along with an 'Autonomous Steering Behavior' lesson as presented by Daniel Shiffman from the Coding Train.  [See Video Tutorials Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1Ws1ZhG36g&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZV4yEcW3uDwOgGXKUUsPOM&index=38)

These lessons are presented using the P5.js library, however I want to follow along using pure JavaScript.

I have created my own `vector` class, as well as a `vehicle` class that represents an object being controlled by forces.

When I run the `vector` class methods in isolation the `add` and `subtract` methods work as expected.  However, when I try to execute `this.velocity.add(desiredVelocity)` in the `vehicle` class, the `velocity` vector returns 'NaN'

The code run in isolation (working as expected) is

```
let v1 = new Vector(10, 10)
let v2 = new Vector(20, 30)
console.log(v1.add(v2)) // Outputs Vector(30, 40)
```

What have I overlooked or am not aware of that is causing `this.velocity.add(desiredVelocity)` to return `NaN`?

```
class Vector{
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x == undefined ? 0 : x, 
        this.y = y == undefined ? 0 : y
    }

    magnitude(){
        return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y); 
    }

    setMagnitude(newMagnitude){
        this.x = this.x * newMagnitude / this.magnitude();
        this.y = this.y * newMagnitude / this.magnitude();
        return new Vector(this.x, this.y);
    }
    
    add(vector){
        this.x += vector.x;
        this.y += vector.y;
        return new Vector(this.x, this.y)
    }

    static subtract(vector1, vector2){
        return new Vector(vector1.x - vector2.x, vector1.y - vector2.y);
    }
}



class Vehicle {
    constructor(){
        this.position = new Vector();
        this.velocity = new Vector();
        this.maxSpeed = 10;
    }

    seek(target) {
        let desiredVelocity = Vector.subtract(target.position, this.position);
        desiredVelocity.setMagnitude(this.maxSpeed);
        this.velocity.add(desiredVelocity)
        console.log('new velocity', this.velocity) // Returns NaN
    }

}

class Target{
    constructor(){
        this.position = new Vector();
    }
}


const vehicle = new Vehicle();
const target = new Target()
vehicle.seek(target)
```

Comment: Might be clearer to do `this.x = x || 0` instead of `this.x = x == undefined ? 0 : x`

Comment: Not enough here to tell.  Probably an initialization issue for either `target` or `this` in vehicle.js

Comment: I have edited my code to include a reproducible example.

Comment: `0 / 0` is `NaN`. That is what `this.x = this.x * newMagnitude / this.magnitude();` comes up to - `this.x` is `0` and `this.magnitude()` is also `0`. `0 * newMagnitude / 0` is `0 / 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Vector#setMagnitude` you are dividing by the value that `Vector#magnitude` returns, which can be `0`. And when `newMagnitude` is also `0` you get `0 / 0` which results in `NaN`.